# "Manifest file was not found" error when creating an S3 QuickSight datasource using AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-quicksight

When using AWS QuickSight API to try and create a datasource pointing to an manifest stored in S3, I always get this error:

```
An error occurred (InvalidParameterValueException) when calling the CreateDataSource operation: Manifest file was not found
```

This occurs using the CLI as well as the C# SDK.  I have confirmed that the manifest is present and correct by manually creating a dataset from it in the QuickSight user interface.  I have tried all kinds of combinations of bucket name/key formats (bucket name, s3 arn, http path, s3 key etc).

I am sending the request as so:

```
aws quicksight create-data-source --cli-input-json file://./create-data-source-cli-input.json
```

Here is the contents of the request (private values replaced with xxxx)

```json
{
    "AwsAccountId": "xxxx",
    "DataSourceId": "85a8e263-a052-42df-abc9-98c6e60678e57",
    "Name": "TestDatasource",
    "Type": "S3",
    "DataSourceParameters": {
        "S3Parameters": {
            "ManifestFileLocation": {
                "Bucket": "xxxx",
                "Key": "xxxx"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Has anybody else run across this?  Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimentation I found that the file specified by the Key in the ManifestFileLocation cannot contain a space in the name.  I tried replacing the space with a + character in the request, and %20, but it still doesn't work.

The only solution I have found is removing any spaces in the manifest file name.  If this is the only solution it seems it must be a bug in the QuickSight SDK.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you a list of things you can try (it may or may not fix your problem)

- First check out the roles

  - you can do it on the console or write one yourself granting quicksight access to s3
    it would look something like this

  ```
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
      {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
          "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
      },
      {
          "Action": [
              "s3:ListBucket"
          ],
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Resource": [
              "arn:aws:s3:::*"
          ]
      },
      {
          "Action": [
              "s3:GetObject",
              "s3:GetObjectVersion"
          ],
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Resource": [
              "arn:aws:s3:::*/*"
          ]
      }
  ]
  }
  ```
- Also look at the other kinds or roles or policies you might need
- If those don't work check out this link [when you can't connect to s3 data source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/troubleshoot-connect-S3.html) but I think you might have already done that.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank-you Joseph, I verified the permissions.  I have checked out the link as mentioned.  I don't understand why it works in the QuickSight console, but not using the AWS SDK.  Could be some sort of permissions error.  The message "Manifest file was not found" is not very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if permission is provided to the specific bucket via QuickSight Manage Access menu.
`Manage Access` -> `Security and Permissions` -> `QuickSight Access to AWS services`